# Smartsheet webhook subscope

Tags: python, webhooks, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to create a webhook with subscope of a specific column in one of my sheets in python with the following code:

```
my_webhook = smartsheet_client.Webhooks.create_webhook(
    smartsheet.models.Webhook({
        'name': 'test 10',
        'callbackUrl': 'https://my_web.com/webhook/test10',
        'scope': 'sheet',
        'scopeObjectId': 0000000000000000,
        'subscope': {'columnIds': [0000000000000000]},
        'events': ['*.*'],
        'version': 1
        }))
```

And when I get the successfully created webhook with its ID, the subscope is missing from the response.
Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the Smartsheet Python SDK, but in general, I often find it helpful to look at the integration test code in the SDK's GitHub repo whenever I have a question about how to implement a certain operation using the SDK. In this case, the [integration test for webhooks](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/tests/integration/test_webhooks.py) in the SDK repo shows the following code for creating a webhook:

```
def test_create_webhook(self, smart_setup):
        smart = smart_setup['smart']

        webhook = smart.models.Webhook()
        webhook.name = 'My Webhook'
        webhook.callback_url = 'https://www.smartsheet.com'
        webhook.scope = 'sheet'
        webhook.scope_object_id = smart_setup['sheet'].id
        webhook.events.append('*.*')
        webhook.version = 1
        webhook.subscope = smart.models.WebhookSubscope({'column_ids': [smart_setup['sheet'].columns[0].id]})

        action = smart.Webhooks.create_webhook(webhook)
        assert action.message == 'SUCCESS'
        assert isinstance(action.result, smart.models.Webhook)
        TestWebhooks.webhook = action.result
```

Notice specifically that the way the `subscope` property is being set differs from what you've posted above. I'd suggest trying to model your code more after this code, to see if you can achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is virtually identical to mine, and subscopes weren't working for me either. I upgraded from smartsheet-python-sdk pip package 2.86 to **2.105**, and now my webhook gets set properly. I also verified that the subscope setting works, which greatly reduces the number of events I have to process.

Here is my code (although it's essentially the same as yours).

```
def createSheetWebhook(name, sheet_id, target, subscope=[]):
    new_webhook = smartsheet_client.Webhooks.create_webhook(
        smartsheet.models.Webhook({
            "name": F"sheet changes for {name}",
            "callbackUrl": target,
            "scope": 'sheet',
            "scopeObjectId": sheet_id,
            "subscope": {
                "columnIds": subscope
            },
            "events": ['*.*'],
            "version": 1
        })
    )
    return new_webhook.result.id
```